# Test for size of aligned_storage

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

For testing whether a particular type fits into an `aligned_storage`, I created the following test structure:

```
template< typename T, std::size_t Bytes >
struct fits_in_storage : public std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(std::aligned_storage<Bytes>::type) >= sizeof(std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T)>::type)>
{};
```

Now I kind of wonder whether such a test is/will be present in the stdlib.
Would hate to reinventing the wheel.

I am using it to check whether a header defined `aligned_storage` (of size `Bytes`) can take an internal data type, which is only available in the actual compilation unit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to test here. The first template parameter of `aligned_storage` specifies the size, whereas the second specifies the alignment. Without the second parameter, are you only testing the most stringent alignment for an object of at most the specified size?

Comment: @DyP Currently yes. Maybe I'll add a third defaulted template parameter to `fits_in_storage`.

Comment: N.B. Because of the *at most the specified size*, there's a guarantee that the most stringent alignment only gets *more* stringent for bigger objects. I.e. if `Bytes >= sizeof(T)`, an object of type `T` will fit and be properly aligned in an `aligned_storage<Bytes>::type`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I like to ensure (using this via `static_assert`).

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee on the size of `aligned_storage<Len, Align>::type` other than it has *at least* `Len` bytes. It could be possible (but is unlikely) that `::type` for a smaller `Len` is bigger than for a larger `Len`.

[meta.trans.other] states, for

> `aligned_storage<std::size_t Len, std::size_t Align =`*default-alignment*`>`
>
> The value of *default-alignment* shall
>   be the most stringent alignment
>   requirement for any C++ object type
>   whose size is no greater than
>   `Len` (3.9). The member typedef type
>   shall be a POD type suitable for use
>   as uninitialized storage for any object
>   whose size is at most `Len` and whose
>   alignment is a divisor of `Align`.

Therefore, any object with a size smaller or equal to `Len` can be stored in an `aligned_storage<Len>::type`. Consequently, your check can be simplified to:

```
template< typename T, std::size_t Bytes >
struct fits_in_storage
    : public std::integral_constant<bool, (Bytes >= sizeof(T))>
{};
```

Which, of course, can be simplified to `Bytes >= sizeof(T)`.

Comment: If a metafunction is needed (rather than just the `Bytes >= sizeof(T)` condition as you suggest) I'd simplify it even further and make it an alias template for `typename std::conditional<(Bytes >= sizeof(T)), std::true_type, std::false_type>::type`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think I also considered that, but the `integral_constant` version is slightly shorter ;) An alias template instead of a `struct` removes 3 characters, though.

Comment: The main benefit IMHO is that alias templates are more lightweight than defining and instantiating new class templates and so are faster to compile.